# Scheduled Refresh in Power BI not working

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a scheduled refresh with a report that I created in the desktop version. I have been browsing around looking for things to do to get my scheduled refresh to work. I even re-did my report in the desktop with the DirectQuery mode, which I read was the only way to get this to work. But now the "scheduled refresh" is gray on the web service and not sure how to get it to update on its own.

Comment: trying to help here, I assume youre trying to schedule refresh for dataset. from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#power-bi-refresh-types , only Import mode allow scheduled / on demand refresh. check that one first? and after that check your gateway

Comment: My answer is only applicable for dashboards that are published to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into "Data Sources" and make sure the authentication methods are correct for all your data sources (just like you had to do inside the Desktop Version)

From the browser, go to your Dashboards area and click on the 3 dots in order to "Manage" your dashboard.

Go into Data Sources from this menu and provide authentication methods and credential.  Make sure you check your connection on each - you need to get a "Success" in order for it to work.

Once you do that, you will be able to go into the Scheduled Refresh option to set that up.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can edit in Settings option in Datasets > Scheduled refresh or you can also refresh by on demand.